# Personal links in tag 'about' texts

Tags: discussion, spam

Having just reached the 1500 mark (yay me!) I added info. to the tags for JNLP and applet over at StackOverflow.

As I was drafting the [information on the JNLP tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info), I was tempted to link to my own [JNLP API demos](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html).  Normally I would have no reservations about doing so.  Many people have found them to be very handy, my name is on the bottom of each page on the site, there is no charge for the code, and I usually add some text that indicates my connection with them.

But when it came to including the link in the 'about WIKI' I hesitated.  These about tags are anonymous, and I feel it is a bit 'underhanded' to link to my own site when posting in an anonymous form.

What do the folks here think?  Let's assume for the moment that the link to ones own site is of relevance to the subject in question.

Edit 1:  As pointed out by nikic:

- The WIKI tag **edits** are **not** anonymous.  The direct link for the edit history on that tag is available amongst 3 links at the bottom of the description on the tag, in the form:

  edit tag wiki|[history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4855415/revisions)|excerpt history
- A search engine supports that the page is 1st ranked (in a subject area that is admittedly very specific - 'small pond'). E.G. Google on "[jnlp demos](http://www.google.com/search?q=jnlp+demos)"/"[jnlp api demo](http://www.google.com/search?q=jnlp+api+demo)".

The first point especially, removes many of my concerns about adding the link.

---

I will not mark this thread closed for at least another 24 hours, to allow time for any counter points to filter through.  ..Said as if marking an answer 'correct' would actually stop *anybody* from making further comment. ;)

---

Edit 2:
JNLP Wiki tag edited to add link to the JNLP API demos.  I also took the opportunity to define the [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) Wiki entry (also with one link to the [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) tool at my site) and significantly expand the [Applet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) Wiki entry.

Now all that is required is for newbies to:

- Notice the Wiki entry pop-up links.
- Follow the links to them, as well as the related links.
- Read the information contained therein, try the demos. etc.
- **Understand** what they are reading and seeing.

Getting that to happen, should be a breeze.  ;)

Comment: The about tag pages aren't anonymous. They have history, there every change is tracked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you feel that this link adds information to the tag info page, I would go for it. It were unfair not to link to your page, if it contained valuable information, just because it's your own page.

As I see it, if I search for "JNLP demos", your page is the first result, so I wouldn't call it pure self-promotion. It seems to be related enough.

Comment: Thanks for your astute comments. As mentioned in the other comment - I will go ahead and add the link.

Answer (score 3):

I say go for it!

> Many people have found them to be very handy

Perfect.  I see no reason why it would be inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  I will go ahead with the extra links (and some further edits) as soon as the local heatwave has passed & I can think straight.